# Can I make an event if someone double-clicked inside a QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

There is already a text in my `QLineEdit`, and I want that if someone double-clicks inside, then the text will disappear (I would use `lineEdit->clear()` for that part). Can someone suggest a solution for this? I'm kinda new in Qt.

Thank you

Comment: You can use the clearButtonEnabled property of QLineEdit instead to get a better user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you truly want such behavior, you can apply an event filter to the widget. A complete example follows:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/doubleclick-clear-filter-39227270
#include <QtWidgets>

class ClearOnDoubleClick : public QObject {
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
            QMetaObject::invokeMethod(watched, "clear");
        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
public:
    explicit ClearOnDoubleClick(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject{parent} {
        addTo(parent);
    }
    void addTo(QObject * obj) {
        if (obj) obj->installEventFilter(this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QWidget ui;
    QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
    QLineEdit edit;
    layout.addWidget(&edit);
    ui.show();
    ClearOnDoubleClick clear{&edit};
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to make your own widget by inheriting from the `QLineEdit` class. In there you would override the [mouseDoubleClickEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent) method. You can then clear the text inside the method.

Note that it's non-standard behavior to clear the text by double click and it may angry your users. Standard I am used to is to select the text/word.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own custom LineEdit by inheriting QLIneEdit Class.

Override the Mouse click events and make your required code (lineEdit.clear()) inside the overridden funtion.